# Unable to add multiple trains in travel_agency schema

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am unable to add multiple trains for the same location as loc_id in the train table is unique. If I don't make loc_id unique, then I will not be able to identify which train the user has booked. Is there any alternative solution to replace unique(loc_id)?

Travel_agency schema
[image]

```
CREATE TABLE locations(
  id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  s_location VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  d_location VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,  
  UNIQUE(id)
);
INSERT INTO
  locations(id, s_location, d_location)
VALUES
  (1, 'delhi','mumbai'),
  (2, 'mumbai','kolkata');

CREATE TABLE trains(
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    train_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    loc_id INTEGER, 
    on_date TIMESTAMP,
    UNIQUE(id),
    UNIQUE(loc_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(loc_id) REFERENCES locations(id)
);
INSERT INTO
  trains(train_name, loc_id, on_date)
VALUES
  ('Rajdhani Express', 1, '2021-12-10 12:00:00'),
  ('Asr Ltt Express', 2, '2021-12-9 13:00:00'),
 ('Avadh Express', 1, '2021-12-14 20:00:00');
```

Comment: Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '1' for key 'trains.loc_id' 0.015 sec

Comment: `UNIQUE(loc_id),` is unnecessary (in error) The is in the `locations` table should be unique, but you can use it multiple times in the `trains` table so remove `UNIQUE(loc_id),`

Comment: To know which train is corresponding to a row in the filter table, the train is to be uniquely identifiable from loc_id as it is the only attribute which connects the filter table to the train table . So I cannot remove unique(loc_id) from the trains table

Comment: `loc_id` does not need to be unique within the `trains` table otherwise as you see, you cannot have 2 trains with the same start and end place even on different dates. So logic say it cannot be unique